# Is $X^8+a \in \mathbb{F}_{49}[x]$ irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^8+a \in \mathbb{F}_{49}[x]$ with $a \in \mathbb{F}_{49}\setminus \{0\}$. Find all $a$ such that $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_{49}$!

What I know is that $\mathbb{F}_{49} \cong \mathbb{F}_7/(t^2+2)$, hence $a = b_1t+b_2$ with $b_1$, $b_2 \in \mathbb{F}_7$. The brute force method would be to try out every single $a$...

But can I just use Eisenstein and say that as long as $a \neq 1$ and $a$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_7$, $f$ is irreducible? Hence I only need to consider the case that $a = b_2$. Is this correct?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{42}$ doesn’t exist, does it?

Comment: Eisenstein only works for integer polynomials (or, rather, it's only _useful_ for polynomials where the coefficients lie in some non-field integral domain).

Comment: There is no such thing as $\mathbb F_{42}$, since $42$ is not a power of a prime. Is this a typo? Is it supposed to be $\mathbb F_{49}$ too?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry it's 49. My mistake!

Comment: @Arthur Shouldn't the generalization of Eisenstein be okay?

Comment: If $a$ is a square, since $-1$ is a square, there is a reduction.

Comment: @Sqyuli Which generalization? Doesn't everything divide everything in $\Bbb F_{49}^\times$? Then how are you going to find a "prime" which divides all the coefficients except for the leading one? Or more accurately, how are you going to find a prime ideal in $\Bbb F_{49}$ which contains all the coefficients except the leading one? Eisenstein has no interesting generalisation that I know of to finite rings.

Comment: I thought about this [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization), but you are right everything divides everything, so it is useless...

Comment: @Mindlack Could you explain me why? And is this "if and only if"?

Comment: This is not iff. Just that if $a=-b^2$, $X^8+a=(X^4-b)(X^4+b)$. (Note that since $-1$ is a square, say, of $i$, then $-b^2=(bi)^2$).

Comment: Arthur: the polynomial is $X^8+a$, not $X^8-a$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $-a$ is not a square in $\Bbb{F}_{49}$. If $-a$ is a square it factors as Mindlack explained. If it isn't, then $-a$ has order $48$ or $16$. In those cases any zero $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ has order $384$ or $128$. But $\Bbb{F}_{49^8}$ is the smallest extension field containing elements of those orders. So $\alpha$ generates a degree eight extension, and then  $f(x)$ is its minimal polynomial. In other words, $f(x)$ is then irreducible.

Comment: Basically because $\ell=8$ is the smallest positive exponent such that $49^\ell\equiv 1\pmod{128}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eisenstein has *nothing* to do with the case. Rather, this story intimately involves the facts that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, and that the degree of an irreducible polynomial is the same as the field extension degree $[k(z):k]$ if $z$ is any one of the roots of the polynomial.

To make typing easier for myself, I’m going to ask about the reducibility of $X^8-b$, and leave it to you to make the substitution $b=-a$. And I’ll simplify things by writing $k=\Bbb F_{49}$.

What’s the meaning of adjoining the eighth root of an element $b\in k$? If the order of $b$ is $m$ (i.e. $b^m$ is the lowest power of $b$ that’s equal to $1$), then the order of $\sqrt[8]b$ will be $8m$. Adjoining $\sqrt[8]b$ to $k$ will involve an extension of degree $\le8$. This degree will be only $1$ exactly when the order of $b$ is $\le6$, i.e. when $b\in\Bbb F_7$. When this degree is less than $8$, $X^8-b$ will be reducible; when equal, $X^8-b$ will be irreducible.

Thus we can say that $X^8-b$ is reducible if and only if $\left[k(\sqrt[8]b\,):k\right]<8$. Let $k_d$ be the (unique, up to isomorphism) field of degree $d$ over $k$, so that $k=k_1$. We have $|k_d|=49^d$ and $|k_d^\times|=49^d-1$. Now, $k_d$ has an element of order $n$ if and only if $n|(49^d-1)$; still calling $m$ the order of $b$, $k_d$ has an eighth root of $b$ if and only if $8m|(49^d-1)$. Putting all this together, $X^8-b$ is reducible if and only if there is $d<8$ with $8m|49^d$. Direct computation shows that this is the case for $m=1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$, but not $16$ nor $48$. Since the numbers on the first list are just the divisors of $24$, we can say that $X^8-b$ is reducible if and only if $b^{24}=1$ in $k$.

All that labor, and the elephant delivered a mouse. I could have said, simply, that if $b^{24}=1$ and $z^8=b$, then $z^{192}=1$ and since $192|(49^4-1)$, you get $z\in\Bbb F_{49^4}$, so that $X^8-b$ is reducible. But would you have understood my motivation?